# Optimize cURL requests to Google API

Tags: performance, php, mysql, curl, google-translate

I have a table in MySQL with approx. 20 million rows and the following columns:

```
id | word_eng | word_indic
```

I have to translate the English word (the value in column `word_eng`) into Indian language (the value in column `word_indic`) using the Google Translate API.

I have written PHP code which spawns multiple cURL requests and fetches data from API and updates it into the table. But this process is quite slow; it takes about 100 to 200 words per second.

I am using `RollingCurl` for multiple cURL requests. I am running this as a cron job.

What's the best way to make it as fast as possible?

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
include_once('functions.php');
include_once('rolling-curl-master/RollingCurl.php');

$table = $argv[1];

$q = "SELECT * from $table where word_indic is null limit 500000";
$result = $conn->query($q); $n = 0;

$urls = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $id = $row['id']; 
    $word = rawurlencode(getName($row['name_eng']));

//getName is a simple function which does some trimming and cleaning up of string

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text='.rawurlencode($word).'&ime=transliteration_en_te&id='.rawurlencode($id);
    array_push($urls, $url);
}
//print_r($urls);

unset($url);


$rc = new RollingCurl("request_callback");

// the window size determines how many simultaneous requests to allow.  
$rc->window_size = 300;

foreach ($urls as $url) 
{
    // add each request to the RollingCurl object
    $request = new RollingCurlRequest($url);
    $rc->add($request);
}
$rc->execute();

function request_callback($response, $info) 
{
    // parse the page title out of the returned HTML
    if (preg_match("~<title>(.*?)</title>~i", $response, $out)) {
        $title = $out[1];
    }

    //echo "<b>$title</b><br />";
    //print_r($info);
    $parts = parse_url($info['url']); 
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
    $id = $query['id'];
    $text = $query['text'];

    //echo "<hr>";
    $trans = json_decode($response)[1][0][1][0];    

    global $conn; global $table; global $urls; global $n;   
    if ($trans != '' and !preg_match('/[a-z]/', $trans)) 
    { 
        $conn->query("update $table set word_indic='$trans' where id='$id'"); $n++;
    }
} 

?>
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `words` (
 `id` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `word_eng` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `word_indic` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `word_eng` (`word_eng`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: I am sorry for being too quick editing your question. Mysql could be indeed a bottleneck. if your table is innodb, then wrapping a batch in a transaction could greatly improve the performance on the mysql side

Comment: Did you track/measure the performance of the different parts of your script? Do you know, whether Google Input Tools have a restriction for requests per second? You may send more requests and get faster results by using Google's [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/?hl=de). Unfortunately this API isn't free.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes my table is innodb and I have set innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 I had put fulltext index on word_eng but not on word_indic. id is varchar and primary key. Can you tell me if proper indexing can improve performance?

Comment: @insertusernamehere Cloud translation API 'translates' the word, what I need is transliteration for which google input tools is a work around and its pretty fast. Not sure how to check if it has per limit request restriction.

Comment: what is varchar size and encoding? 255 with utf8 will make something 760 bytes

Comment: @YourCommonSense It is varchar(50) and utf8. I think select and update should be done with fulltext match? Will that improve things? Adding fulltext index to a column full of null values, how good is that?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I were talking of the id field, which is, on your word, a primary key. To clear that up, just add the table definition to your question and also the tag mysql which I erroneously removed

Comment: I know you were talking about id varchar(50). I asked will it help to add fulltext index on word_indic varchar(100) and doing `select` query on `where word_indic is null`

Comment: I have added table definition to the main question.

Comment: i would make a numeric autoincremented primary key

Comment: You do have a lot of boilerplate code from the [Rolling cURL examples](https://github.com/LionsAd/rolling-curl), while you actually only need to this line: `$trans = json_decode($response)[1][0][1][0];`. Running `preg_match` unnecessarily can be a huge overhead.

Comment: Agree a numeric primary key would make `where id =`  faster. I had to use `preg_match` because sometimes the api returns the original english word back as it cant translate it and I want to avoid insert such words in my table. Can we do this without `preg_match`.

Comment: I actually meant the other `preg_match` and the whole part from `$title` to `$text`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Url building

> ```
> $id = $row['id']; 
> $word = rawurlencode(getName($row['name_eng']));
> //getName is a simple function which does some trimming and cleaning up of string
> $url = 'https://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text='.rawurlencode($word).'&ime=transliteration_en_te&id='.rawurlencode($id);
> ```

Could be simplified with the use of [http_build_query()](http://php.net/http_build_query) with encoding type **`PHP_QUERY_RFC3986`** to replace the [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode):

```
$row['text'] = getName($row['name_eng']);
//unset $row['name_eng'] or select it as "text" in the SELECT statement
$row['ime'] = 'transliteration_en_te'; //or move into SELECT fields in query?
$url = 'https://www.google.com/inputtools/request?'.http_build_query($row, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

Obviously that will likely result in extra parameters tacked onto the URL (e.g. `word_indic`, `word_eng`). You could update the select query to specifically select those fields:

```
$q = "SELECT id, name_eng as text from $table where word_indic is null limit 500000";
```

And you *could* select that `ime` parameter as a hard-coded value, so as to not need to assign it to each row in the `while`, but then that would make the result set larger...

#### Global variables

I see this line:

> ```
> global $conn; global $table; global $urls; global $n;
> ```

In general it isn't a good habit to be referencing variables globally. Obviously this is in the context of a callback function but there are ways to avoid that. I would suggest creating a wrapper class and storing the connection, table and other info in member/instance variables while calling the method using the array syntax.

The [Singleton Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) could be used to create a wrapper class on the database code and call a static method to get a connection to the database, instead of referencing `$conn` globally.

Also, `$urls` and `$n` don't appear to be used after that line anyway...